# Trouble using import in C++20

Tags: c++, c++20

Now that most of the compilers have adequate support for C++20. This code below, which uses the import module should compile without errors and warnings. But when I compile the code using g++ I get the following error [Code Compilation Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLrce.png)

I've read [Overview of Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-160) but having hard time to understand given that I'm fairly a beginner in programming. Is there anything wrong that I'm doing or missing that the code won't run?

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdlib>
import <algorithm>;
import <fstream>;
import <initializer_list>;
import <iostream>;
import <iterator>;
import <locale>;
import <string>;
import <system_error>;
import <vector>;

template<class C>
struct text : std::basic_string<C>
{
  using super = std::basic_string<C>;
  constexpr text() noexcept : super{} {}
  text(text&&) = default;
  text(text const&) = default;
  text& operator=(text const&) = default;
  text& operator=(text&&) = default;
  constexpr explicit operator bool() const noexcept {
    return not this->empty();
  }
};

/// Read lines of text from @p in to @p iter. Lines are appended to @p iter.
/// @param in the input stream
/// @param iter an output iterator
template<class Ch>
auto read(std::basic_istream<Ch>& in) -> std::vector<text<Ch>>
{
    std::vector<text<Ch>> result;
    
    text<Ch> line;
    while (std::getline(in, line))
        result.emplace_back(std::move(line));

    return result;
}

/// Main program.
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
try
{
    // Throw an exception if an unrecoverable input error occurs, e.g.,
    // disk failure.
    std::cin.exceptions(std::ios_base::badbit);

    // Part 1. Read the entire input into text. If the command line names a file,
    // read that file. Otherwise, read the standard input.
    std::vector<text<char>> text; ///< Store the lines of text here
    if (argc < 2)
        text = read(std::cin);
    else
    {
        std::ifstream in{argv[1]};
        if (not in)
        {
            std::cout << argv[1] << ": " << std::system_category().message(errno) << '\n';
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        text = read(in);
    }

    // Part 2. Sort the text. The second command line argument, if present,
    // names a locale, to control the sort order. Without a command line
    // argument, use the default locale (which is obtained from the OS).
    std::locale const& loc{ std::locale(argc >= 3 ? argv[2] : "") };
    std::collate<char> const& collate{ std::use_facet<std::collate<char>>(loc) };
    std::ranges::sort(text,
        [&collate](auto const& a, auto const& b)
        {
            return collate.compare(to_address(cbegin(a)), to_address(cend(a)),
                to_address(cbegin(b)), to_address(cend(b))) < 0;
        }
    );
 
    // Part 3. Print the sorted text.
   for (auto const& line :  text)
      std::cout << line << '\n';
}
catch (std::exception& ex)
{
    std::cerr << "Caught exception: " << ex.what() << '\n';
    std::cerr << "Terminating program.\n";
    std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
catch (...)
{
    std::cerr << "Caught unknown exception type.\nTerminating program.\n";
    std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

(The code is taken from the website of the book `Exploring C++20 by Ray Lischner` [Website](https://cpphelp.com/exploring/exploring-20/))

Comment: Hmm, `<algorithm>` etc are not a modules. They are header files that should be `#include`d. Though, Visual Studio has an extension that lets you `import` the headers as modules: `import std.core;` will import all those headers you have listed for example.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo the code above is a part of the example from the book Exploring C++20. According to the writer, imports can be use for header files since C++20. So do I need to use Visual Studio for it? Because at the moment, I'm using neovim as an editor and g++ as my compiler.

Comment: My module game is lame, but isn't there a global module fragment declaration missing somewhere in this code?

Comment: [gcc.gnu.org - Modules](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Modules.html) "_The Standard Library is not provided as importable header units. If you want to import such units, you must explicitly build them first. If you do not do this with care, you may have multiple declarations, which the module machinery must merge—compiler resource usage can be affected by how you partition header files into header units._"

Comment: "Now that most of the compilers have adequate support for C++20." That unfortunately is not true for some major features like modules and coroutines - see [cppreference C++ compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support). Microsoft is actually the sole exception here.

Comment: Thank you guys for your valuable comments. @Ted Lyngmo going through the linked website clears everything. I'll stick to using #include for now.

Comment: @AlanBirtles: The book is correct to the standard; `import <header-name>` ought to be able to work, for any header. The problem is that many standard library implementations do not write their standard library headers in a way that would allow this to work.

Comment: According to the gcc [doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-modules) 
_Header Units are traditional header files that are (separately) compiled with the -fmodule-header flag. They each produce a BMI, and are imported into user code with an import declaration naming a header unit._